# How to set attributes back to it's default values?

Tags: css

I have a CSS file where I set the input to different values other than the default.

```
input[type=text]{
   text-align: center;
   border: none;
   background-color: #EBEBEB;
   border-radius: 5px;
   width: 100%;
   padding: 12px;
   margin-top: 25px;
   display: inline-block;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   font-family: "Lucida Sans Typewriter", "Lucida Console", monaco, 
  "Bitstream Vera Sans Mono", monospace;
}
```

Now I want to use this INPUT somewhere else on the webpage with default values. How can i set it to default only to that particular part of the webpage without damaging the rest of the INPUT?

Comment: Give your input a class instead of applying a global style that affects all input elements?

Comment: Give your input a ID and override whatever style attributes you want to..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anot) and a additional class to solve this:

```css
input[type=text]:not(.default) {
   text-align: center;
   border: none;
   background-color: #EBEBEB;
   border-radius: 5px;
   width: 100%;
   padding: 12px;
   margin-top: 25px;
   display: inline-block;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   font-family: "Lucida Sans Typewriter", "Lucida Console", monaco, 
  "Bitstream Vera Sans Mono", monospace;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="Hello StackOverflow"/>
<input class="default" type="text" value="Hello StackOverflow"/>
```

A better solution, as already mentioned in the comments of your question, is to use scopes using a class. So format only specific `<input type="text"/>` elements using a class! See the following example:

```css
input[type=text].style1 {
   text-align: center;
   border: none;
   background-color: #EBEBEB;
   border-radius: 5px;
   width: 100%;
   padding: 12px;
   margin-top: 25px;
   display: inline-block;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   font-family: "Lucida Sans Typewriter", "Lucida Console", monaco, 
  "Bitstream Vera Sans Mono", monospace;
}
```

```html
<input class="style1" type="text" value="Hello StackOverflow"/>
<input type="text" value="Hello StackOverflow"/>
```